# How does DNF figure out how to find and install a package to a Linux machine?

Tags: rpm, yum, dnf

I have been using `dnf install <package_name>` for years. Recently I have become curious as to how the `dnf install` command knows how and where to go on the Internet to find and install a particular package.

I know that `.repo` files are stored in the directory `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Does `dnf install` do an inspection of the `.repo` files in the directory `/etc/yum.repos.d` to discover a repository's location on the Internet and then peruse the repository to find the particular package? Then, once the package `.rpm` is located and the file's URL is determined, does the `dnf install` command download the `.rpm` file and do installation against the downloaded file?

I am embarrassed to say that I am not sure how it all works under the covers. Any insights anybody can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I describe the process by which `dnf` or `yum` discovers an RPM package in the following diagram:

[image: DNF Discovery process]